# Creating a slug with UTF-8 in it

Tags: php, regex, utf-8, slug

I am trying to write some code to take UTF-8 text and create a slug that contains some UTF-8 characters. So this is not about transliterating UTF-8 into ASCII.

So basically I want to replace any UTF-8 character that is whitespace, a control character, punctuation, or a symbol with a dash. There exist [Unicode categories](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#category) that I should be able to use: `\p{Z}`, `\p{C}`, `\p{P}`, or `\p{S}`, respectively.

So I could do something as simple as this:

```
preg_replace("#(\p{P}|\p{C}|\p{S}|\p{Z})+#", "-", "This. test? has an ö in it");
```

but it results in this:

```
This-test-has-an-√-in-it
```

(and I'd want `This-test-has-an-ö-in-it`)

It butchers the *umlaut o*, possibly because in Unicode it is comprised of two bytes `c3b6` of which the `b6` seems to be recognized as a punctuation character (so the `\p{P}` matches here). The `c3` remains in the text. This is strange because AFAIK a single byte `b6` doesn't exist in UTF-8.

I also tried the same thing in Perl in order to make sure it is not a PHP problem, but the code

```
$s = 'This. test? has an ö in it';
$s =~ s/(\p{P}|\p{C}|\p{S}|\p{Z})+/-/g;
```

also produces:

```
This-test-has-an-√-in-it
```

(which probably makes sense as PHP's PCRE are Perl Compatible Regular Expressions)

While when I do this in Python

```
import regex as re
text=u"This. test? has an ö in it";
print re.sub(ur"(\p{P}|\p{C}|\p{S}|\p{Z})+", "-", text)
```

it produces my desired

```
This-test-has-an-ö-in-it
```

What to do?

Comment: Interesting question, but if you are creating slugs for URLs, would it not be better to convert them to ASCII?

Comment: I don't think so, with modern browsers it is not a problem to have UTF-8 in URLs so they will be much more readable. Even if the browser has to resort to urlencoded bytes (a la `%C3%B6` for an `ö`) in the background.

Comment: That's true, yes. However, even Stack Overflow itself transliterates to ASCII characters ([see here](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%C3%B6)), which perhaps makes it easier to type URLs in.

Comment: Well, Stack Overflow is not the end of all wisdom :) And if you speak the language you will probably have the means to write it. In my case there is also a short URL without the slug (and in ASCII) which is meant to be typed if necessary, I claim that nowadays the slug is mainly there for search engines anyway.

Comment: _Stack Overflow is not the end of all wisdom_ - it isn't? `=:-O`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to use the "Unicode modifier" `u`:

```
preg_replace("#(\p{P}|\p{C}|\p{S}|\p{Z})+#u", "-", "This. test? has an ö in it");
```

correctly produces

```
This-test-has-an-ö-in-it
```

So: using Unicode Categories without the Unicode modifier produces strange results without any warning.